# How to Allow tags in HTML Purifier?

Tags: php, htmlpurifier

How do I allow the marquee tag in html purifier http://htmlpurifier.org/ I read the docs but I couldn't find anything. Does any one have a clue?

Answer (score 9):

Marquee is not, and was ever, a valid HTML tag, so HTML Purifier doesn't support it even if you set HTML.Allowed. You'll have to follow the instructions here to add support for it: http://htmlpurifier.org/docs/enduser-customize.html